# Is it possible to alter an unsigned `exe`?

Tags: windows

I would like to increase an `exe` size without altering the behavior of it. Is it possible to fill it with blank data?

Comment: If it was signed with Authenticode, it likely will render the signature invalid, I do think?

Comment: Ah, but Uwe, he said "unsigned".  And an unsigned app definitely can be altered -- viruses do this all the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  This was a common trick to avoid the "no games in the office" rules in the 90s.
Just append data to the end.  IIRC they (never me ;-) used the append `>>` command line to do this.

Example:

```
copy %windir%\notepad.exe test.exe
echo "appended data" >> test.exe
test.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for the example @Jader.  I was feeling too lazy to verify the syntax. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you could use a resource editor to add an empty resource section.

Why do you want to do this?

Comment: LULz, same question.

Comment: I want to delay a download for debugging purposes

Comment: Throttling the network connection (globally or locally) makes more sense to me than padding an .exe file.  Of course, it does depend on what you need to debug.

Answer (score 1):

It can be an issue for some anti virus software but windows loader doesn't care about any extra data.